# First child on it's own line

Tags: css

I want to make my .screen class to be on its own line. Assuming I can not change the current layout.

```html
<div class="app">
    <div class="screen"></div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

I though that `display: block;` would do the trick but no.

```css
.screen {
    display: block;
}
```

As of now it all sits on one line. I am only handy with flex and I can't think of anyway flex will help me here.

Comment: Divs are block level by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using flexbox `flex-wrap` can help. Make the first child 100% wide and put `flex-wrap: wrap` to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

By default, browsers always place a line break before and after the `<div>` element. However, this can be changed with CSS. There is probably override of `<div>` style.

Try to use !important to prioritize your style:

```
.screen {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Also, check the style of div in browser's inspector and provide that info – it would be useful to get more details